# how to link bootstrap to My blade file in laravel npm install?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm

I am working with laravel 5.6 and install bootstrap with npm. this is My blade file,

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Acxian</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 </head>
    <body>
<div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Acxian
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but above bootstrap is not working, how can link npm link with blade file?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is a default package in laravel. Since you have installed it, then just run
`npm run dev` to compile them into `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` then you can link them to your blade files via `{{asset('css/app.css')}}` and `{{asset('js/app.js')}}`.